# IOS terminal build fails for Facebook review - normal i386

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, terminal, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build my Unity project for approval for Facebook publish-action using the terminal.
but every time i try it fails with the following message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"Alg::Compression::Lzma::decode(Alg::Compression::Lzma::CompressPrefix, void*, unsigned long, unsigned char const*, char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
    Pfx::Asm::Lzma::uncompress(unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned char const*, unsigned long) in libiPhone-lib.a(asmlzma.o)
    "__storeKitCanMakePayments", referenced from:
    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
    "__storeKitCancelDownloads", referenced from:
    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
    "__storeKitDisplayStoreWithProductId", referenced from:
    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
    "__storeKitFinishPendingTransaction", referenced from:
    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
    "__storeKitFinishPendingTransactions", referenced from:
    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
    "__storeKitForceFinishPendingTransactions", referenced from:
    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
    "__storeKitGetAllSavedTransactions", referenced from:
    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
    "__storeKitGetAppStoreReceiptUrl", referenced from:
    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
    "__storeKitPauseDownloads", referenced from:
    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
    "__storeKitPurchaseProduct", referenced from:
    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
    "__storeKitRequestProductData", referenced from:
    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
    "__storeKitRestoreCompletedTransactions", referenced from:
    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
    "__storeKitResumeDownloads", referenced from:
    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
    "__storeKitSendTransactionUpdateEvents", referenced from:
    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
    "__storeKitSetApplicationUsername", referenced from:
    RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
        clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

            ** BUILD FAILED **


            The following build commands failed:
            Ld build/stabelyapp.app/stabelyapp normal i386
            (1 failure)
```

What's wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my Unity project and it has been resolved removing -all_load from Other Linker Flags in XCode ( Build Settings > Linking > Other Link Flags ).

I hope it helps.